# HTML5 canvas not restoring rotation in Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, canvas

This code is not working as I expected in *Firefox* (17.0.1). I expect it to write the line in the same position every time I call the `drawLine` function with the same parameters. And in *Chrome* and *IE* this is the case. But in *Firefox* running it the second time seems to continue the rotation of the new line from where the first one was draw giving me two lines. It would be nice if someone could explain why it behaves this way.

T

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function draw(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');

  if (canvas.getContext){
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = '#993333'       
    drawLine(ctx, 100,100,100,200);
    drawLine(ctx, 100,100,100,200);
  }

  function drawLine(context, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    context.save();
    context.translate(x1, y1);
    context.moveTo(0, 0);
    context.rotate(1);
    context.lineTo(x2,y2);
    context.stroke();
    context.restore();
  }

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="draw();">
   <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its working as expected for me in firefox 17.0.1 http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/kMPLQ/1/

Comment: Hi Loktar. So you are only seeing one line? Cause I'm not when I look at the jsfiddle you made?

Comment: Yeah only one line :? and FF *just* updated when I opened it to test the fiddle, to 17.0.1. I was hoping you had more code causing the issue. Pretty weird.

Comment: Do you have anymore information you could share? @Loktar's jsfiddle worked also

Comment: I'm running Win7 64. My colleague is also seeing what I'm seeing. However he also tried it on a virtual win7 32 and then it was correct. We'll keep digging.

Comment: Also works on a virtual Win7 64 so seems there are something on our machines that makes this happen. I'll let you know when (if) I figure it out. Thanks for testing it guys.

Comment: I also see two lines on my home machine (Win7 64)?!

Comment: One line on my other home machine(Win7 32)

Comment: You need to `beginPath` and `closePath`, sir.

Comment: Side note, why are you translating/rotating the canvas in the first place?

Comment: I'm actually drawing multiple lines and want to rotate the final shape. I just simplified it as much as possible in the example to focus on the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should fix it.

```
function drawLine(context, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    context.save();
    context.translate(x1, y1);
    context.beginPath();       // <--- start a new path. If you don't do this, previous paths may get mixed in with the one you're currently drawing.
    context.moveTo(0, 0);
    context.rotate(1);
    context.lineTo(x2,y2);
    context.closePath();      // close that path. 
    context.stroke();
    context.restore();
}
```

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/kMPLQ/2/

Comment: That worked. Thanks Shmiddty. Strange that it behaves differently on different machines though. Would be interesting to know why.

Comment: It seems to have something to do with 32/64 bit system differences.